# Kubernetes 1.24 enable insecure port or disable TLS

Tags: kubernetes

We are using actually k8s HA multi master cluster version 1.24 within a **SSL/TLS encrypted, secured and access restricted private network behind a hardware firewall**. Our cluster has **no public endpoints** or any communication to the public internet. We want to disable TLS for the k8s cluster or at least using an insecure way for internal k8s communication. At version < 1.24, there were **--insecure flags** for the kube-apiserver, which has been **removed since 1.24**.

Do version 1.24 provide any alternative for the removed --insecure flags?
How to achieve an insecure communication with 1.24?

Answer (score 2):

[Insecure address flags](https://github.com/rancher/cis-operator/issues/158) are used to serve unsecured unauthenticated access to the API server. Setting up the apiserver to serve on an insecure port would allow **unauthenticated** and **unencrypted access** to your master node. This would allow attackers who could access this port, to easily take control of this cluster.

[Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md) release of 2022(1.24+) aims to make Kubernetes more secure and reliable. In the 1.24 release, there is a single essential change for the kube-scheduler. Insecure flags, such as `--address` and `--port`, have been [removed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/106865). It is suggested to use [**--bind-address and --secure-port**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) instead. So, there is no alternate option of using an insecure way for internal kubernetes communication.

Comment: Thanks, but i have to sorry: Your answer almost completely misses the question, except the line with "..no alternate..". Please read more than just the title next time :)